# Xcode C++ development, clarification needed

Tags: c++, xcode

I absolutely love the way Xcode offers insight into possible available member functions of the language and would prefer to use it relative to, say, text mate, if not for an oddity i noticed today.

When `string s = "Test string";` the only available `substr` signature is as shown

[image]

From what i understand however, and what [i see online](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) the signature should be

```
string substr ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos ) const;
```

Indeed `s.substr(1,2)`; is both understood and works in Xcode.

**Why does it not show when i try to method complete? (Ctrl-Space)**

Comment: I am fairly sure that the best you can do at this point is to file a bug report.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Xcode is performing the completion correctly, but it's not what you expect.  You've actually answered the question yourself unknowingly.  The function signature for `string`'s `substr()` method, just as you said, is:

```
string substr ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos ) const;
```

All arguments to `substr()` have default assignments, therefore to Xcode, `s.substr()` (with no arguments) is the valid code completion to insert because it's *really* `s.substr(0, s.npos)`.  You can confirm this with any number of standard C++ functions with default arguments.  The easiest place to see this is with any STL container constructor.

Take for instance a `vector`.  We all know that `vectors` can take an `Allocator`, but the default argument assigned `Allocator` is "good enough" for most casual uses.  Sure enough, two of the signatures for `vector` constructors are:

```
explicit vector ( const Allocator& = Allocator() );
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

In both cases, the `Allocator` argument has a default assignment, and in the second, the `T` default value has a default assignment.  Now, take a look at what Xcode suggests when constructing a `vector`:

[image: Xcode 4.2.1 Code Completions for vector constructor]

The suggestion with no argument list is *actually* the constructor that takes just an `Allocator`.  The suggestion that takes just a `size_type` is *actually* the constructor that takes a `size_type`, `T`, and `Allocator`.

Depending on how you think about this, it may or may not be an Xcode bug.  Ideally, you want to see completions with default arguments for simpler functions like `substr()`, but for STL container constructors, you probably almost never want to see them.  Perhaps it could be an option, but I wouldn't expect to see this corrected.  I'd happily dup a radar with you though.

Comment: Bug or feature depending on what behavior you may prefer.

Comment: @krynr given that it's a completely valid completion, it's not a bug.  Clearer UI on the matter, though, is probably desired.  Auto-completing to 0,  s.npos might be a feasible option here, but it's possible it would be less preferable in some cases (i.e. you're effectively saying "use the defaults" but the auto-complete would hard code it to the defaults at the time of coding, which may not be desirable).

Comment: @James: You're telling me Apple can't do it better?

Comment: It's not a matter of doing better, it's a matter of adding yet-another preference.  My guess is that 95% of the people using Xcode are using it for Objective-C development.  It's probably not worth the code, man-power, or additional preference for the fraction of people who do C++ development and are inconvenienced by this behavior.